# How to replace keyboard with another view without flicker?

Tags: android, keyboard

I have to replace soft keyboard with a view in my layout.

I don't need to show PopupWindow over keyboard!

I have a view (let's say its height is the same as the keyboard). It is placed in the bottom of the screen. I am hiding it when I am showing the keyboard. And showing it back when the keyboard is gone.

The issue is that the view is jumping (flickering) for half second before the keyboard is shown (or hidden).

```
toggleButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    if (picker.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        showKeyboard();
        picker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        hideKeyboard();
        picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

I need some kind of "batch layout" after both picker view and the keyboard are toggled.

Here is the video demo of the issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jPVX22C86s

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `android:animateLayoutChanges="false"` inside the parent layout.

Or you need to set `OnTouchListener` to mainLayout of the View where you need to hide the KeyBoard.

Comment: The question was - how to avoid flicker? I don't have any animations at all.

Comment: Yeah I got your question but its default flicker. So that you need to change it.

Comment: Hey, I have added a video demo. It will help u understand the issue